# does the mui framework provide chip sizing flexibility beyond medium/small?

Tags: reactjs

Does the MUI framework provide chip sizing flexibility beyond medium/small?  For example, a business may request having an option for an xs chip.  I was thinking that the Chip "sx" property might provide a hook for that but when I try to use the "sx" property in my app like this:

```
<Chip
    sx={{height:10}}
/>
```

then intellisense displays an error of "No overload matches this call."  I used the sx prop to configure height for an Icon in codesandbox.io a few weeks ago but can't find the url.

Is the sx prop as I'm using it above to set Chip height valid?  Is there a particular minimum version dependency for mui that I need to ensure in order for this to compile/function properly?

Comment: Something else might be wrong in your code. I'm able to get sx to work https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-owajhk?file=demo.js. Chip api only calls for small and medium.

Comment: thanks rolando!  that works perfectly!  I think the issue might be that mui didn't support the "sx" property before v.5.0. the app that I'm currently working on uses mui v.4.11.  any idea what kind of approach you would have used to set a custom height property for a chip like that before v.5.0?